# Adding to the results of a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written the following program in order to add "1" to the code we assign mail that comes into the office.  The user puts in input on a form and the query brings back the last code assigned for the state and company.  The program should increase that number by 1.  Example TN08801401 (TN - COCODE 0880 Year - 14 - Sequence 01) should now be TN08801402.

The program worked fine as long as the query brought a result.  If the answer was null (meaning that it was the first state/company/mail we had, then I wanted the program to create the code. Example WA08801501.

The problem is that it only giving me the errorsub routine instead of the base program.

Thanks,

Here is the code as follows:

```
Private Sub form_load()
Dim qryrslt As String
Dim State As String
Dim num As String
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim num2 As Integer
Dim num3 As String
Dim total As String
Dim CoNo As String
Dim yearseq As String

On Error GoTo errorsub


qryrslt = DLookup("[idkey]", "assignment_qry")
State = Left(qryrslt, 6)
num = Right(qryrslt, 4)
If IsNumeric(num) Then
    num1 = CInt(num)
Else
    num1 = 0
End If
num2 = num1 + 1
num3 = CStr(num2)
total = State + num3

Me.TxtIdKey = total


errorsub:
    State = Forms!assignment_form!CmbState
    CoNo = Forms!assignment_form!CmbCompany
    yearseq = 1501
    total = State + CoNo + yearseq
    Me.TxtIdKey = total
```

Comment: not understand what you asking, which query return result??

Comment: it seams to be a type mismatch. Are you sure that your query result is a string ? also you'd better use "&" to concatenate string instead of "+"

Answer (score 1):

It is always simpler to concatenate fields together, rather than split them apart. It appears that your 'idkey' is a single field made up of multiple values. You would be better off using a separate field for each value and concatenating them as needed. Let's say your table is tblPrograms. Fields would be ProgState (text), ProgCode (text), ProgYear(integer), ProgSequence (integer). Anywhere you need it, you can concatenate ProgState & "-" & ProgCode & ProgYear & ProgSequence. To get the next sequence is a simple lookup.

```
Dim intNewSequence as Integer 
intNewSequence = Nz(DMax("ProgSequence", "tblPrograms", "ProgState ='" & Forms!assignment_form!CmbState & "' AND ProgCode = '" & Forms!assignment_form!CmbCompany & "' AND ProgYear = " & Forms!assignment_form!ProgYear), 0) + 1
```

Additionally, this makes any queries that would use any of those fields in a where clause, much more efficient.

Comment: I am still very new at this!  I don't understand what the above program is doing?  Should I be creating a new table with the split of the idkey?

Comment: No, you don't create a new table. It seems that your current table has a text field [IDkey] that contains values like TN08801401, which you create from various different elements. Instead of that one field, you should remove it and have a separate field for each element. Then anywhere that you need to display the 'idkey', you simply concatenate all of the elements together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to need to do a null check before you assign State & num. Sorta like this:

```
if (qryslt is not null) 
{State = Left(qryrslt, 6)
num = Right(qryrslt, 4)
If IsNumeric(num) Then
    num1 = CInt(num)
Else
    num1 = 0
End If
num2 = num1 + 1
num3 = CStr(num2)
total = State + num3

Me.TxtIdKey = total}
```

Sorry if the syntax isnt right for vb - it's been a while, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I had changed the error sub to a Is not Null.Now I am getting a Run Time Error 424.  
    qryrslt = DLookup("[idkey]", "assignment_qry")

If qryslt Is Not Empty Then
    State = Left(qryrslt, 6)
    num = Right(qryrslt, 4)
        If IsNumeric(num) Then
            num1 = CInt(num)
        Else
            num1 = 0
        End If
    num2 = num1 + 1
    num3 = CStr(num2)
    total = State + num3
    Me.TxtIdKey = total
Else
    State = Forms!assignment_form!CmbState
    CoNo = Forms!assignment_form!CmbCompany
    yearseq = 1501
    total = State + CoNo + yearseq
    Me.TxtIdKey = total
End If

Answer (score 0):

I split the add into two steps to make this work.  Step 1 was to find the last in sequence or create a default:

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()

Dim Qry As String
Dim State As String
Dim num As String
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim num2 As Integer
Dim num3 As String
Dim total As String
Dim CoNo As String
Dim yearseq As String

Qry = "" & DLookup("IDKEY", "Assignment_qry")

If Qry = "" Then
    State = Forms!assignment_form!CmbState
    CoNo = Forms!assignment_form!CmbCompany
    yearseq = 1500
    total = State + CoNo + yearseq
    Me.TxtAssignment = total
Else
    Me.TxtAssignment = Qry
End If

End Sub
```

Then I added one in another step:
Private Sub form_load()

```
Dim qryrslt As String
Dim State As String
Dim num As String
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim num2 As Integer
Dim num3 As String
Dim total As String
Dim CoNo As String
Dim yearseq As String

qryrslt = Forms!assignment_form!TxtAssignment

State = Left(qryrslt, 6)
num = Right(qryrslt, 4)
    If IsNumeric(num) Then
    num1 = CInt(num)
    Else
    num1 = 0
    End If
num2 = num1 + 1
num3 = CStr(num2)
total = State + num3
Me.TxtIdKey = total
Me.TxtCompany = Mid(State, 3, 5)
Me.TxtCoName = DLookup("Name", "Newentry_coname_qry")
```